# Slide Menu opened swipe and button

Tags: swift, button, menu, swipe

> I have a Slide Menu. Open menu on pressed button. I need add swipe to
>   open menu too. I make two func. But opened two menu - one where press
>   button and one when swipe))) I need ones menu opened. Help me please
>
> its code of Button and on image code of SWIPE

```
 [@objc public func onSlideMenuButtonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){
        if (sender.tag == 10)
        {
            // To Hide Menu If it already there

            self.slideMenuItemSelectedAtIndex(-1);

            sender.tag = 0;

            let viewMenuBack : UIView = view.subviews.last!

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                var frameMenu : CGRect = viewMenuBack.frame
                frameMenu.origin.x = -1 * UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
                viewMenuBack.frame = frameMenu
                viewMenuBack.layoutIfNeeded()
                viewMenuBack.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    viewMenuBack.removeFromSuperview()
            })

            return
        }

        sender.isEnabled = false
        sender.tag = 10

        let menuVC : MenuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        menuVC.btnMenu = sender
        menuVC.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
        self.addChildViewController(menuVC)
        menuVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()


        menuVC.view.frame=CGRect(x: 0 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height);

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            menuVC.view.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height);
            sender.isEnabled = true
            }, completion:nil)
    }


    public func openMenu(){

        SwipeRigtYES = true
//        sender.isEnabled = false
//        sender.tag = 10
        let menuVC : MenuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
//        menuVC.btnMenu = sender
        menuVC.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
        self.addChildViewController(menuVC)

    }

    public func closeMenu(){
        SwipeRigtYES = false

        let viewMenuBack : UIView = view.subviews.last!

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frameMenu : CGRect = viewMenuBack.frame
            frameMenu.origin.x = -1 * UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
            viewMenuBack.frame = frameMenu
            viewMenuBack.layoutIfNeeded()
            viewMenuBack.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            viewMenuBack.removeFromSuperview()
        })
```

> And swipe

```
 @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {
            print("Swipe Right")
            if SwipeRigtYES==false {
                 openMenu()
                print("open")
            }else {
            print("Else")
        }




        }
        else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left  {
            print("Swipe Left")
            if SwipeRigtYES==true {
                closeMenu()


                print("close")
            } else {
                print("Else")
            }
```

> Please help me
>   Maybe I need one func with clicked button and swipe action to open Menu

Answer (score 0):

First make the menuView as a var inside the main VC , second while performing the menu animation make a bool that omits any subsequent clicks until animation finishes whether the action sender is the swipe or the button click